# sklearn tfidf vectorizer - remove n-2 and n-1 grams if n gram exists

Tags: python, scikit-learn, n-gram, tfidfvectorizer

I am using sklearn's tfidf-vectorizer to create a document-feature matrix and list of feature terms.

I do not want repeating n-1 and n-2 grams, if an n-gram already exists. I.e., `for an example sentence: The quick brown fox jumps over the fence`.

I want to `not include` terms `'fox' and 'brown fox'  if 'quick brown fox' exists.`

My hypothesis is that repeating tokens causes an artificial expansion of the feature set and distorts results of other tasks such as clustering.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I am running into the same problem

Comment: Not yet. Sorry.

Answer (score 6):

I know it's not an efficient way to do this but this is what i did.
Using pandas series at the end just to subset the array with the selected indices.

```
def removeSubgrams(features):
  # Sort features based on length of the n-gram
  features = sorted(features , key=lambda x:len(x.split(" ")))

  to_remove = []

  # Iterate over all features
  for i,subfeature in enumerate(features):
    for j,longerfeature in enumerate(features[i+1:]):
      if longerfeature.find(subfeature) > -1:
        to_remove.append(i)
        # break if subfeature is a substring of longerfeature
        break
  features = pd.Series(features)
  # keep only those features that are not in to_remove
  features = features.loc[~features.index.isin(to_remove)]
  return features
```

Answer (score 0):

Sklearn's tfidf-vectorizer contains a key-word 'ngram_range' that allows you to specify n-grams. You should also consider using the 'stop_words' key-word.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

corpus = ['The quick brown fox jumps over the fence']
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(3, 3), stop_words='english')
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)

print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
```

Generally it depends on your corpus, whether you want to chose unigrams, bigrams, trigrams, etc. In order to choose, you will need to evaluate the performance of your algorithm. For example use the Roc curve, Information Gain, Accuracy, etc. and see which n-gram yields the best performance.

Comment: Thank you, but doing this does not give me the bigrams that I need- for instance 'jumps over'. I need to get a complete ngram range (0,3) and then filter out bigrams where trigrams exist (for example remove 'quick brown' and 'brown fox' because 'quick brown fox' exists.

Answer (score 0):

@apokhi
I modified the code to keep the original order of "features".

```
features=['a','a b c','b','d']
features_sorted = sorted(features, key=lambda x: len(x.split(" ")))
for i, subfeature in enumerate(features_sorted):
    for longerfeature in features_sorted[i + 1:]:
        if longerfeature.find(subfeature) > -1:
            features.remove(subfeature)
            break

print(features)
```