# Remove 1-grams if 2+ grams are present in text

Tags: python, string, text, nlp

I'm getting the following output from my function
`[(I, None), (love, 'B2'), (ice, 'A2'), (ice cream, 'A1'), (cream, 'A2'), (and, 'A1'), (the, 'A1'), (the second person, 'B2'), (second, 'B1'), (person, 'A1')]`. However, the text I need to return must be the same as input `"I love ice cream and the second person"`, so I need to remove all the 1-grams if there's any 2+ gram containing the same word in vicinity.

So far I've tried this solution [sklearn tfidf vectorizer - remove n-2 and n-1 grams if n gram exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57528505/sklearn-tfidf-vectorizer-remove-n-2-and-n-1-grams-if-n-gram-exists) but I struggle to put these 2+ grams back in the place they've been to.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Do you really get this output, without quotes around the words? This makes it an invalid structure.

Comment: Good remark! I actually do as it is some kind of Spacy's type that can be converted to a string.

Comment: You should provide valid Python data (with quotes around the strings...) correctly representing your real situation, with the exact expected output. In your current sample data, it looks like you just have to remove the tuples with 2+ grams, as they always match the surrounding words exactly. If this isn't always the case, show us what we should expect to see!